# What is the Shiny default font?

Tags: r, shiny

What is the Shiny default font? Where to look it up?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage("What font is used here?")

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Probably just the default bootstrap font? https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/cad20a0bfea9d02dc9f163f028a0c498462fdd90/R/bootstrap-layout.R#L89

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not find the font in this file.

Comment: Well not in the exact file, but since its just using bootstrap: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/cad20a0bfea9d02dc9f163f028a0c498462fdd90/inst/www/shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css#L1085

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well using the HTML inspect tool in Internet Explorer we find that Shiny is using `"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif` as default text-font and as @Caramiriel already mentioned is this taken from bootstrap.min.css

[image: screenshot of HTML inspect tool show which fonts are used]