# How to change the font family of verbatimTextOutput to be the same as the input in Shiny and Shinydashboard?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to change the font family of the `verbatimTextOutput` to be the same as the input in Shiny and Shinydashboard. Here is an example.

```
# Load the packages
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = ""),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          text = "Example",
          tabName = "tab1"
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "tab1",
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 4,
              numericInput(inputId = "Number", label = "A numeric input", value = NA),
              strong("The same number as the numeric input"),
              verbatimTextOutput("Number_out")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$Number_out <- renderText(as.character(input$Number))
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By running the app and type in a number, we can see that the font family is different in the `numericInput` and the `verbatimTextOutput`.

[image]

Based on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48037443/7669809) and this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50784117/7669809), I edited my script as follows.

```
# Load the packages
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = ""),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          text = "Example",
          tabName = "tab1"
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(
          HTML(
            '#Number_out {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            }'
          )
          )
        ),
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "tab1",
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 4,
              numericInput(inputId = "Number", label = "A numeric input", value = NA),
              strong("The same number as the numeric input"),
              verbatimTextOutput("Number_out")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$Number_out <- renderText(as.character(input$Number))
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But the font family is still not the same.

[image]

It seems like I have not used the correct font family yet. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `font-family:  'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`

So your `tags$head` will be:

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      "#Number_out {
       font-family:  'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
       font-size: 14px;
        }"
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

In Chrome, if you right click and click on Inspect then scroll down to find relevant style elements:
[image]

And on bottom right you can see:

[image]

Comment: I just edited the answer to find out the font information

Comment: Thanks, again. Stack Overflow does not allow me to reward you the bouty right away. I will do that when I am allowed to do so.